# Mysql connection with C program

Tags: mysql, c, linux

Can anyone help me to **Connect C program to mysql databse in Linux environment**. I am again repeating only **C program gcc-4.9.2**.

Tell me also packages to compile and execute the program. Since I didn't find a good source on internet to do this if u provide some links that will be so pleasing...

Comment: do not expect us to do your work for you.  We will point out problems in posted code.  Suggest performing a bit of research, code the application as best you can, then post that code.

Answer (score 2):

A simple `access mysql from c program` google search yielded many useful web links that show you how to get started. It's high time you learn how to use these basic things. Also, similar questions exist in StackOverFlow.

At StackOverFlow, we are not going to do everything for you. Show us the minimal effort that you've put into this problem.

Btw, start from here : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-c/en/